# How to run a function when the user clicks a RouterLink to the current path?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way to detect if there has happened a navigation or navigation attempt?
The obvious way is to do this:

```js
const route = useRoute()

watch(route, () => {
  // some code
})
```

But this way if the user presses a `RouterLink` that is pointing to the page that is already opened nothing happens.

I'm making a dropdown menu that is a sibling to the `RouterView` and it is supposed to close if the user tries navigating even if he's navigating to where he already is.

Another way is to put an `@click` listener on every visible `RouterLink`, but that seems suboptimal.

None of the [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) seem to get triggered also.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `router.afterEach` does get triggered on redundant navigation. That solves my issue.